# Using decimals in Javascript function with variables (0.01)?

Tags: javascript

I want to make this project, to where when you upgrade, it will increment to 0.01 Click Per Second Automatically, instead of 1 click per second. I am pretty sure this has to do with a function, but I am a beginner and cant find anything on how to change it, and dont have the knowledge. Is there a variable I have to change, or what? Whenever I try to change the `var auto_clicks = 0;` to `var auto_clicks = 0.01;` it doesn't work. What code should I add or change to make this work?

```
//variables
var clicks = 0; //increment this by one every click
var auto_clicks = 0; //automatically click once per second
var cost = 1; //the cost of this should increase exponentially
var upgrade_speed = 0; //the level of the speed up upgrade
var click_rate = 1000; //ms between each autoclick
var interval_auto; //storing our interval here so we can update it
var click_increment = 1; //how many clicks per click
//functions

function update_total_clicks() { //updates the number of clicks   
    var e = document.getElementById("total_clicks");
    e.innerHTML = clicks;
}

function buy_something(c, button) {
    if (clicks < c) {
        button.className = 'btn btn-danger';
        setTimeout(function() {
            var e = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-danger")[0];
            e.className = 'btn btn-success';
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
    clicks -= c;
    return true;
}

function update_workers() {
    var e2 = document.getElementById("time_period");
    e2.innerHTML = parseFloat(click_rate / 1000.0).toFixed(2);
    clearInterval(interval_auto);
    interval_auto = setInterval(function() {
        clicks += auto_clicks;
        update_total_clicks();
    }, click_rate);
}
//click events
document.getElementById("click").onclick = function() {
    clicks = parseFloat(clicks) + parseFloat(click_increment);
    update_total_clicks(); //updates the text
};
document.getElementById("buy_click").onclick = function() {
    if (!buy_something(cost, this)) return;
    auto_clicks++;
    cost = Math.pow(2, auto_clicks); //new cost
    update_total_clicks();
    var e = document.getElementById("clicks_per_second");
    e.innerHTML = auto_clicks;
    var e2 = document.getElementById("buy_click");
    e2.innerHTML = 'Buy for ' + cost;
    var e2 = document.getElementById("autoclicker_level");
    e2.innerHTML = 'lvl  ' + auto_clicks;
};
document.getElementById("upgrade_speed").onclick = function() {
    var upgrade_cost = (Math.pow(3, upgrade_speed)) * 100;
    if (!buy_something(upgrade_cost, this)) return;
    upgrade_speed++;
    click_rate = click_rate * 0.90;
    update_workers();
    var e2 = document.getElementById("upgrade_speed");
    e2.innerHTML = 'Buy for ' + ((Math.pow(3, upgrade_speed)) * 100);
    var e2 = document.getElementById("speed_level");
    e2.innerHTML = 'lvl  ' + upgrade_speed;
};

//Increase Click Increment
document.getElementById("increase_clicks").onclick = function() {
    var upgrade_cost = (Math.pow(3, click_increment)) * 1;
    if (!buy_something(upgrade_cost, this)) return;
    click_increment++;
    update_workers();
    var e2 = document.getElementById("click_increment");
    e2.innerHTML = 'Buy for ' + ((Math.pow(3, click_increment)) * 100);
};

//Start Autoclickers
update_workers();

function set_cookie(cookie_name, value) {
    expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setTime(new Date().getTime() + (10 * 60 * 1000));
    var c_value = escape(btoa(JSON.stringify(value))) + "; expires=" + expiry.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cookie_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function get_cookie(cookie_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + cookie_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(cookie_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) return false;
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1) {
        c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = atob(unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end)));
    return JSON.parse(c_value);
}
```

Comment: it would be very helpful if you add your html and make a snippet to demonstrate your code

Comment: Isn't `click_rate` what you want to edit? The comment seems to say it does what you are aiming for. (Assuming you actually mean add 1 click per 100 seconds, rather than add 0.01 click every second)

Comment: There's a lot of code here that doesn't seem related to the question

Comment: Yeah sorry here is the full code: https://codepen.io/samuelbeard/pen/Dsdie

Comment: Also editing click rate isn't the problem, because I dont want the amount of clicks to be 1. I want it to be 0.01 every time there is an Autoclick. So basically once someone buys an Autoclick upgrade, they can get 0.01 clicks per second to start.